# Paperback novel about a man who kills a birdlike alien on his balcony with a watering can

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it as a paperback book somewhere in the mid-90s, I think. The protagonist lived in an apartment building. He's out on the balcony when a birdlike (but humanoid) alien swooped down and attacked him. The presence of the aliens was commonly known and was a known danger. He kills it with his watering can and is rewarded by either the aliens or the humans for it with money. Other than that, all I remember was that the chapters were started with an internet-like news report which I think chronicled things getting worse and more violent. One of the updates involved the bombing of a bridge with the casualties raised by having two slow-moving trucks moving side by side obstructing traffic and ensuring a full bridge.

The internet system was pretty ubiquitous as I recall. I think that he looked up his watering can shortly after the incident with the aliens, but decided to keep this one, even if it leaks a bit. I want to say that it was by Piers Anthony, but none of the book titles look familiar. I think the cover I had showed the man being attacked by the bird-man, which looked kind of like the illustrations on the cover of *The Stand*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably Kevin O'Donnell's [ORA:CLE.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425072606)

It takes place in a fairly far-future where global warming has forced the entire (surviving) population of earth into living completely indoors in large apartment/office towers. There are matter transporters that can only send non-living items (it kills living things). Some time after everyone moves into these towers the Earth is invaded by winged aliens called Dacs (short for ptera*dac*tyls). The Dacs don't seem to care about taking over in any usual sense, they just keep us from developing space travel and hunt us for sport - but only if we go outside.

[image]

Here's part of the scene with the watering-can and the winged alien:

> He moved. Whirling to his right, he swung the
>   watering-can like a tennis racket, wristing it up and into an overhead
>   backhand shot. He had plenty of time because time had slowed. A sub
>   broke water in New Haven harbor. The wrought-iron railing cast a
>   short, slanted shadow. The Dac mothership drifted three klicks
>   overhead. His lungs were already
>   laboring.
>     To his right, great bat-wings
>   fluttered as the Dac tried to balance itself. The five-centimeter
>   claws of its knobbly eagle’s feet skidded slightly on the flagstones.
>   Its carrot-colored beak snapped in frustration, flashing razor-sharp
>   teeth and a predator’s hook to the upper jaw. Its huge head bounced on
>   its child-sized torso. Its hand—with a thumb, three fingers, and
>   retractable claws—wavered as it tried to aim the gun that gleamed like
>   silver.
>     Ale had spun nearly a hundred and
>   eighty degrees. Thinking, *But the damn alarm was guaranteed!* he
>   hurled the watering-can.

After killing the alien, other aliens (of the same species) come to investigate and apparently decide that this was a "fair killing". The cut off the dead one's beak and give it to the main character as a trophy.

Comment: That's the one. Thank you. Weirdly enough, I saw that book title in my searches, but it just didn't look right. This is also apparently the second time I've tried to look up a book by this author...

Comment: It's a surprisingly decent book. I happened to re-read it a few months ago.

Comment: I was reminded of it recently when reading *Welcome to the Ark*, where terrorists used a similar ploy with a bridge to increase the death toll.