# Story ID: Star-based computers, human thought, climate change, god and religion

Tags: story-identification, religion, computers, quantum-physics

I just had a dream and I can't figure out if it's just based on memories of what I've read or seen. Is anyone familiar with a plot similar to the following?

So it goes:

In a distant future, some company has created some sort of computer system based on using the Sun as a quantum computer, deploying some type of satellite system around the sun to harness its computational power.

Humanity is in a crisis, because weather is going crazy and scientists have figured out, queries entered in the Oracle system -- some futuristic version of Google -- by all of humanity are causing the structural instability of our Star, the Sun.

Changes in the Sun directly cause erratic climate changes which are making life on earth hard to bear.

There's chaos cause this computer is such a critical piece of humanities infrastructure it cannot simply be shut down.

In this futuristic highly-technological society there are whole groups of people for which the weather changes are direct punishment of humanities bad behaviour. In some sense humanity has reverted to a state where they perform sacrifices/acts of redemption to calm the negative impact of their bad thoughts -- via the queries they do in the Oracle system --.

It seems in my dream that's the plot twist, from an outsider's perspective society seems to behave based on superstition, the believe that the gods of the weather are punishing their bad deeds but from the insider's perspective, they have a scientific understanding that it is their thoughts which cause the structural instability of their Sun and therefore all the climatic chaos.

Answer (score 2):

This could be [ORA:CLE](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1455438.ORA), a 1986 novel from the American author Kevin O'Donnel jr.

I've only been able to find reviews on Goodreads so far but the plot does cover some of the points in the question.

> Recommends it for: sci-fi lovers

> One of the more realistic books I ever read about a plausible future. Spotted with some fantastic elements -not enough relevant to sustract reality- presents a world worried about CO2 emissions, natural catastrofes, social knowledge and other.

Climate Change driven disasters seem to be a major part of the plot and the protagonist is a computer user of the titular ORA:CLE network.

I haven't found any mention of the use of the sun in a quantum computer network though so far.

Comment: I'll check my copy, but I don't remember there being a sun-based computing system.

Comment: And if so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85261/paperback-novel-about-a-man-who-kills-a-birdlike-alien-on-his-balcony-with-a-wat